# Cannot Insert List of ItemDetail ie.List<ItemDetail> (OBJECT) into a MySQL DataBase Feild through Hibernate using SpringMVC

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to create a table named '**invoicedto**' in which,I have a field consisting a list of **ItemDetail** (POJO Object).

I need clarification on following:
1.Can we Insert a List of Object in a field in MySQL database?
   If possible then how to do? What should be my datatype of column in MYSQL?
2.If we cannot insert a list?Is there any other method to achieve this scenario?

If have attached my code below:

**Controller**:

```
@Controller
public class InvoiceController {

@Autowired
InvoiceService invoiceService;

public void setInvoiceService(InvoiceService invoiceService) {
    this.invoiceService=invoiceService;
}


@RequestMapping("/invoice/add")
public ModelAndView addInvoice(){
    Map<String,Object> businessDataMap=new HashMap<>();
    ModelAndView modelAndView=new ModelAndView();
    String invoiceNumber = invoiceService.generateInvoiceNumber();
    businessDataMap.put("invoiceNumber", invoiceNumber);
    modelAndView.addAllObjects(businessDataMap);
    modelAndView.setViewName("add_invoice");
    return modelAndView;
}
}
```

**Service**:

```
package com.company.greeninvoice.service;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.company.greeninvoice.dao.InvoiceDao;
import com.company.greeninvoice.dto.Customer;
import com.company.greeninvoice.dto.Invoice;
import com.company.greeninvoice.entity.ItemDetail;

@Service
public class InvoiceServiceImpl implements InvoiceService{

public static final String EMPTY_STRING = "";

public static final String INVOICE_CODE = "INV";

public static final String SEPERATOR = "-";

public static final String DEFAULT_INVOICE_NUMBER = "0000";

public static final String INVOICE_FORMATTER = "%04d";

@Autowired
InvoiceDao invoiceDao;

public void setInvoiceDao(InvoiceDao invoiceDao){
     this.invoiceDao = invoiceDao;
  }

@Transactional
@Override
public String generateInvoiceNumber() {
    insertRecord();
    String invoiceNumber = EMPTY_STRING;
    return invoiceNumber;
}

private void insertRecord() {
    Invoice invoice=new Invoice();
    LocalDate todayDate=LocalDate.now();
    String yearCode = String.valueOf(todayDate.getYear()%1000);
    String monthCode = LocalDate.now().getMonth().name().substring(0, 3);
    String invoiceNumber=INVOICE_CODE+SEPERATOR+yearCode+monthCode+SEPERATOR+"0001";
    invoice.setInvoiceNumber(invoiceNumber);
    Customer customer=new Customer();
    customer.setCustomerName("VENKAT");
    customer.setMale(true);
    invoice.setCustomerDetails(customer);
    invoice.setTotalAmount((float) 25.02);
    invoice.setInvoiceDate(Date.valueOf(todayDate));
    List<ItemDetail> itemdetailsList=new ArrayList<>();
    ItemDetail itemDetail=new ItemDetail();
    itemDetail.setSerialNumber("1");
    itemDetail.setItemDescription("Pencil");
    itemDetail.setItemQuantity(2);
    itemDetail.setItemRate(25);
    itemDetail.setAmount(50);
    itemdetailsList.add(itemDetail);
    invoice.setItemdetailsList( itemdetailsList);
    invoiceDao.addInvoice(invoice);
}
}
```

**DAO**:

```
package com.company.greeninvoice.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.company.greeninvoice.dto.Invoice;

@Repository
public class InvoiceDaoImpl implements InvoiceDao{

private static final Logger logger = 
LoggerFactory.getLogger(InvoiceDaoImpl.class);

@Autowired
SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
     this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
  }

@Override
public void addInvoice(Invoice invoice) {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.persist(invoice);
    logger.info("Invoice saved successfully, Invoice Details="+invoice);
}

}
```

**Model**:

1.**InvoiceModel**:[Should I use,**ElementCollection** Annotation?]

**Problem**:**List<ItemDetail>** not Inserted.

```
package com.company.greeninvoice.dto;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CollectionTable;
import javax.persistence.ElementCollection;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.CollectionId;

import com.company.greeninvoice.entity.ItemDetail;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Setter;

@Data
@Entity
@Setter
@Table(name="invoiceDto")
public class Invoice implements Serializable{

@Id
private String invoiceNumber;

private Date invoiceDate;

private Customer customerDetails;

@ElementCollection
private List<ItemDetail> itemdetailsList;

private float totalAmount;
}
```

**Entity POJO Class**:

```
package com.company.greeninvoice.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Entity
public class ItemDetail  implements Serializable{
@Id
 private String serialNumber;

 private String itemDescription;

 private int itemQuantity;

 private float itemRate;

 private float amount;

 }
```

**Tomcat Console in Eclipse**:

```html
Hibernate: insert into invoiceDto (customerDetails, invoiceDate, totalAmount, invoiceNumber) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Invoice_itemdetailsList (Invoice_invoiceNumber, itemdetailsList) values (?, ?)
Jan 21, 2018 5:50:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/greeninvoice] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement] with root cause
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'itemdetailsList' in 'field list'
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:939)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3878)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3814)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2478)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2625)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2551)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2073)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2009)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5094)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1994)
 at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
 at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:187)
 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:62)
 at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.recreate(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1311)
 at org.hibernate.action.internal.CollectionRecreateAction.execute(CollectionRecreateAction.java:67)
 at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:463)
 at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:349)
 at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
 at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1222)
 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
 at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
 at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
 at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:555)
 at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757)
 at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726)
 at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:478)
 at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:272)
 at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
 at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy26.generateInvoiceNumber(Unknown Source)
 at com.company.greeninvoice.controller.InvoiceController.addInvoice(InvoiceController.java:35)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
 at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
 at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
 at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

[Folder Structure of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYacd.png)

[InvoiceDto Table structure in MySQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgUSr.png)

Comment: To insert a list of details, think about how to have a separate table with foreign key and have that relation built into POJO. Then you can add as many details you want and save them all at once.

Comment: Do you have the separate table for Itemdetails? If no, Why do you have @Entity on its pojo?

Comment: @Rakesh no I don’t need to maintain separate table for itemdetails .If I remove Entity annotation will it work

Comment: never tried MySQL json type, I need to do some research but yes you do not need @Entity on top of itemdetails pojo. Can't guarantee you that it will work but that is the first fix that you should be doing. We can proceed with later issues later.

Comment: What data type should I specify in MySQL for List of pojo?

Comment: It's your choice(blob,json,etc), guess you will be needing a custom entity listener to cast the itemdetails pojo from list to json and json to list while inserting and retrieving

Comment: @Rakesh  thanks for quick and kind reply.Sorry ,I can’t get you.if I use blob do it need to be casted?

Comment: yes to a byte array and if json you need to convert that list to  json string

Comment: Ok will it affect performance?

Comment: eventually, you will be needing that list so it is better to convert that list to a json string using object mapper(why I am saying an object mapper because I am not sure if spring JPA does list to json casting). It won't take a lot of time for casting, if you are gonna do bulk insert/retrieve you might have a performance issue.

Comment: @Rakesh thanks for remembering object mapper :)

Comment: make sure you add your answer once you come up with a fix. It might help me in future development.

Comment: @Rakesh sure I’ll post fix in this thread next week I’m on vacation

Comment: @Rakesh I removed Entity annotation and tried to insert im getting error of could not determine type for List.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Invoice` and `ItemDetail` are annoatated with `@Entity`,You should use JPA relationship annotations (which including `@ManyToMany, @ManyToOne, @OneToMany, @OneToOne`) instead of using `@ElementCollection`. I assume your invoice includes many items, So i would use `@OneToMany` annoation on `List<ItemDetail>` like this:

```
@OneToMany
private List<ItemDetail> itemdetailsList;
```

If you still want to use `@ElementCollection` on `List<ItemDetail>` you have to use `@Embeddable` annoation on `ItemDetail`

```
@Data
@Embeddable
public class ItemDetail  implements Serializable{
 @Id
 private String serialNumber;

 private String itemDescription;

 private int itemQuantity;

 private float itemRate;

 private float amount;

 }
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.Sorry I’m new to hibernate and JPA.Can You explain why we use elementCollection and embeddable annotations?

Comment: `@ElementCollection` is used on a collection . If you are using this annotation on, for example  `List<String>` or `Set<Double>` etc.. there is no need for `@embeddable` annotation. If you are using it on `List<yourOwnCreatedClass>` then you need to annotate yourOwnCreatedClass with `@embeddble` annotation. for more information you can check this link:https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ElementCollection

Comment: I have another doubt .what is differences between JPA and CURD repositories .which should I implement

Comment: I would suggest you to use `JpaRepository` since it extends `CrudRepository` and `PagingAndSortingRepository` and have both interface's properties

Comment: I dont need to save this Item Detail in separate table instead i need just to store pojo values in single feild

Comment: Can i know the reason why you want to do this.

Comment: storing item detail in another table makes difficult to view

Comment: If you execute query on `Invoice` like this `select i from Invoice i`. this will give all invoice along with `ItemDetail` in list of object. There is no need to combine `ItemDetail` fields in `Item` entity.

Comment: i made code changes as you said but i cant able to insert

Comment: im getting error like:org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of //@OneToMany or  //@ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.company.greeninvoice.dto.Invoice.itemdetailsList

Comment: please help to fix this

Comment: Can you upload code to github and provide me link. So that i can import code in my STS

Comment: wait ill provide git link

Comment: please reply after seeing

Comment: You have used `@Entity` and `@Embeddable` on item detail . remove `@Embeddable` and try again

Comment: wait ill check in my machine

Comment: oi have commited sql files for ur reference

Comment: But why we should remove  @Embeddable annotation

Comment: You should use either `@Entity` or `@Embeddable` . Since you have used `@OneToMany` on list of itemDetail in Item entity and not `@ElementCollection`. thats why i asked you to remove `@Embeddable`

Comment: How to insert Map<String,Object>

Comment: i would suggest you to use a class instead of using Map<String,Object> and use jpa relational annotation over it

Comment: I don't have any sample code right now. you have to search online